# How to post json data directly in Rest API with python

Tags: python, json, rest, api, post

I have a response data which is in json format, now I want to post this json format.But I have issues with same.

```
{'u_correlationid_': '', 'resolved_by': '','active': 'true', 'upon_approval': 'proceed', 'skills': '', 'parent_incident': '', 'business_impact': '', 'sys_domain': {'value': 'global', 'link': ''}, 'made_sla': 'true', 'activity_due': '2019-11-07 10:09:15', 'opened_at': '2019-09-11 16:17:24'}
```

When I tried directly posting the json data I had error:

```
"error": "Validation error - JSON parse error: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@37b90445; line: 1, column: 298] (through reference chain: java.util.LinkedHashMap[\"sys_domain\"])"
```

I want to fix this error in Python and also post my json data with `"` instead of `'` format of my response
E.g-`{"u_correlationid":""}` and at last I also want to append one key pair to existing before post.
E.g-

```
{"u_correlationid":"",
"opened_at": "2019-09-11 16:17:24","data":"big"}
```

Comment: Show us the code used to post it!

Comment: It seems from the error that the JSON being posted by you and the server, are not matching. Please confirm the JSON schema once. And to append a new key to dictionary, simply use dictionary[new_key] = new_value.

Comment: It seems from the error that the JSON being posted by you and the server, are not matching. Please confirm the JSON schema once. And to append a new key to dictionary, simply use dictionary[new_key] = new_value.

Comment: How to check for the JSON schema?I couldnt provide code as i am now tring with swagger ui.